# How to loop Simple password login count attempts

Tags: vbscript, passwords

```
fso = InputBox("To verify that you're the system administrator of this computer, please enter your login password.")

Dim oShell, cntAttempts
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
cntAttempts = 0

if fso <> "PASSWORD" then 
cntAttempts = +1
end if
if cntAttempts = 3 Then
oShell.run ("notepad.exe")
wscript.Quit 
end if 


if fso = "PASSWORD" then
oShell.run ("calc.exe")

end if
```

Hello everyone,
I have tried the simple code above that would ask for simple password. I can't get the count attempt to work right, I need it to ask for the right password at least 3 times before it executes a script for the wrong password. Please help! thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you need to repeat an action more than once you will need to use a loop, like a `Do` or `For` loop.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart, that got me in the right direction.